In Ansible, add an element to every dict in a list of dicts, but multiply it by an existing entry
I have a list of dicts:
vars:
  sites:
    - name: "Tampa"
      site_number: 0
    - name: "Miami"
      site_number: 1
    - name: "Daytona"
      site_number: 2

I want to add an entry to every dict in this list, but multiply it by a value. I have tried the following:
- set_fact:
    sites: >-
      {{
        sites | map('combine', {
          'site_subnet': '172.16.0.' + (item.site_number*8)|string + '/29',
          'test1': item.site_number
        }) | list
      }}
  loop: "{{ sites }}"
- debug: var=sites

Now, the resultant output shows that sites[n].test1 is always 2, and of course, the site_subnet is always 172.16.0.16/29. What is the malfunction with my code?

Ansible is generally not a great tool for modifying data structures. You can get what you want by creating a new variable, like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sites:
      - name: "Tampa"
        site_number: 0
      - name: "Miami"
        site_number: 1
      - name: "Daytona"
        site_number: 2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        new_sites: >-
          {{
            new_sites + [item | combine({
              'site_subnet': '172.16.0.' ~ (item.site_number*8) ~ '/29',
              'test1': item.site_number
            })]
          }}
      loop: "{{ sites }}"
      vars:
        new_sites: []

    - debug:
        var: new_sites

This results in the following output (which is what I think you want):
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_sites": [
        {
            "name": "Tampa",
            "site_number": 0,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.0/29",
            "test1": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Miami",
            "site_number": 1,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.8/29",
            "test1": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Daytona",
            "site_number": 2,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.16/29",
            "test1": 2
        }
    ]
}


For any sort of complex logic, I always find it more managable to use a custom filter instead. I would drop the following into filter_plugins/filters.py:
def filter_update_sites(sites):
    return [
        site | {
            "site_subnet": f"172.16.0.{site['site_number']*8}/29"
        }
        for site in sites
    ]


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "update_sites": filter_update_sites,
        }

And then write the playbook like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sites:
      - name: "Tampa"
        site_number: 0
      - name: "Miami"
        site_number: 1
      - name: "Daytona"
        site_number: 2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        new_sites: "{{ sites | update_sites }}"

    - debug:
        var: new_sites

Which produces:
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_sites": [
        {
            "name": "Tampa",
            "site_number": 0,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.0/29"
        },
        {
            "name": "Miami",
            "site_number": 1,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.8/29"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daytona",
            "site_number": 2,
            "site_subnet": "172.16.0.16/29"
        }
    ]
}


Create a list of subnets
  subnets: |
    {% for i in sites %}
    - {site_subnet: 172.16.0.{{ i.site_number * 8 }}/29}
    {% endfor %}

gives
  subnets: |-
    - {site_subnet: 172.16.0.0/29}
    - {site_subnet: 172.16.0.8/29}
    - {site_subnet: 172.16.0.16/29}

and combine the result
  result: "{{ sites | zip(subnets|from_yaml) | map('combine') }}"

gives
  result:
    - {name: Tampa, site_number: 0, site_subnet: 172.16.0.0/29}
    - {name: Miami, site_number: 1, site_subnet: 172.16.0.8/29}
    - {name: Daytona, site_number: 2, site_subnet: 172.16.0.16/29}



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sites:
      - {name: Tampa, site_number: 0}
      - {name: Miami, site_number: 1}
      - {name: Daytona, site_number: 2}

    subnets: |
      {% for i in sites %}
      - {site_subnet: 172.16.0.{{ i.site_number * 8 }}/29}
      {% endfor %}
    result: "{{ sites | zip(subnets|from_yaml) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: subnets

    - debug:
        var: result | to_yaml



Based on How to keep appending new keys to a dictionary when using set_fact module with with_items? (annot: where is also a Custom Filter Plugin mentioned), a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    sites:
      - name: "Tampa"
        site_number: 0
      - name: "Miami"
        site_number: 1
      - name: "Daytona"
        site_number: 2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sites[item.site_number] | combine(_append_dict) }}"
      loop: "{{ sites }}"
      vars:
        _append_dict:
          site_subnet: "172.16.0.{{ (item.site_number * 8) | string }}/29"
          test: "{{ item.site_number }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Tampa', 'site_number': 0}) =>
  msg:
    name: Tampa
    site_number: 0
    site_subnet: 172.16.0.0/29
    test: '0'
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Miami', 'site_number': 1}) =>
  msg:
    name: Miami
    site_number: 1
    site_subnet: 172.16.0.8/29
    test: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Daytona', 'site_number': 2}) =>
  msg:
    name: Daytona
    site_number: 2
    site_subnet: 172.16.0.16/29
    test: '2'

